# How to migrate users from user service database to spring boot auth server database?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I am building a micro service bases spring boot application. In order to protect my rest APIs, i have implemented spring boot authorization server to provide oauth2 tokens to users. Currently i have users in master database under the table users. Authorization server is authenticating users from the authorization database under its users table. Do i need to migrate all my users from my master database to authorization server database? or should i call an API to user service and authenticate users?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your overall architecture, but in General you do not need to migrate users, you can check the permissions of users by calling the API of the service that stores these users.

In my opinion, this is the preferred way to divide microservices into an authentication/authorization microservice and a user information storage microservice, since user information is not related to authentication/authorization and has low connectivity, so you can easily change the authentication/authorization microservice in the future.

But there are also opposite points of view, in favor of combining authentication/authorization microservices and user storage. The main advantage of this approach is the simplicity of managing and supporting a single microservice.